# Comment appelle-t-on une affirmation ou une moquerie cachée dans une question ?

Tags: questions, figure-de-style

Comment s'appelle la figure de style lorsqu'une affirmation (voire une moquerie) est « cachée » dans une question ?

Par exemple :

> Comprends-tu si je te dis que tu es intelligent ?

Peut-être une « [litote](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litote) » ?

Comment: @user2572030: Soit dit en passant, est-ce un "loaded question" en anglais ?

Answer (score 4):

A ma connaissance, on appelle une affirmation déguisée en question une *question rhétorique*. Dans ce cas-là c'est une question qui n'attend pas de réponse, la réponse étant contenue dans la question elle-même (ou s'impose immédiatement et sans ambiguïté dans l'esprit de l'interlocuteur).

> Penses-tu vraiment que je sois content que tu aies cassé ce saladier ?

Mais dans l'art du discours, une question rhétorique peut aussi amener l'orateur à répondre lui-même à sa question pour valider son argument.

> L'accusé était-il présent sur les lieux ? Non. Était-il responsable du premier accident ? De même, non. L'accusation n'a donc aucunement lieu d'être !

La question rhétorique peut prendre la forme d'une moquerie :

> Tu te crois intelligent ?

d'un compliment : (répondre à sa propre question lève les ambiguïtés s'il y en a dans l'esprit de l'interlocuteur)

> Y-a-il meilleur que toi pour préparer les champignons ? (J'en doute !)

d'un constat :

> Au fond, n'est-ce pas l'Homme qui décidera de l'avenir de la planète ?

etc. Tout dépend du sens de l'affirmation cachée dans la question rhétorique.

---

Note : le contexte et l’intonation d'une question rhétorique joue énormément. Ainsi, la question :

> Tu crois vraiment qu'il existe des extraterrestres ?

posée avec un véritable étonnement traduit l'intention de se renseigner sur les croyances de l'interlocuteur ; cette même question posée d'une manière dubitative reflète la non-croyance du locuteur.

Comment: La question  rhétorique semble suffisamment neutre pour correspondre au cas général. Je pense que cela peut-être en plus une moquerie, un compliment ou simplement un constat. Dans ce cadre,  pensez-vous que le « n’est-ce pas ?» correspond  une question rhétorique ? Par exemple : Il est intelligent, n’est-ce pas ?

Comment: En partie. Le "n'est-ce pas" en fin de phrase invite plutôt l'interlocuteur à valider ou réfuter l'affirmation ("il est intelligent, n'est-ce pas ? -Non, je ne trouve pas."). Mais il peut aussi intervenir dans une question rhétorique : "Au fond, n'est-ce pas l'Homme qui façonne la planète selon ses désirs ?".

Comment: J'ai modifié la réponse avec des compléments d'informations à propos du sens de la question rhétorique.

Answer (score 2):

Certainement pas "litote", qui est faire semblant de dire moins, ou pas du tout, pour signifier plus :

"Va, je ne te hais point". = "Je t'aime".

---

"question ironique", "fausse interrogation", "persiflage" sont possibles, mais moins précis et moins bons que le "question rhétorique" proposé par user2572030.

---

"Prétérition" figure de style par laquelle on feint d'omettre ce que l'on mentionne en fait, pourrait convenir dans certains cas.

"Et je ne parlerai pas de ce que tu as fait hier !" = je ne l'ai nullement oublié et te le rappelle.

"Je me demande qui a bien pu casser ce vase ?" = je sais bien que c'est toi

Answer (score 2):

Je crois que *sarcasme* décrit bien cette situation.

Wikipedia :

> Le sarcasme (du grec ancien σαρκασμός / sarkasmos) désigne une moquerie ironique, une raillerie tournant en dérision une personne ou une situation.

Answer (score 0):

En langage courant c'est une *vacherie*, c'est à dire une énoncée blessante supportée par l'*ironie*, c'est une *satire* qui selon wikipédia est

> "Une satire est une œuvre dont l'objectif est une critique moqueuse
>   de son sujet." (*[wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satire)*)

Il n'y a strictement aucun humour, car la critique n'est pas adressée au locuteur mais à sa victime, sans aucune empathie, dénotant un égoïsme où le complexe de supériorité cherche à humilier l'autre 
... à moins que ce ne soit deux génies qui s'amusent de l'*[Oulipo](http://www.oulipo.net/)* (répondre alors "Comprends-tu ce que tu dis ?")